# Time Limit for Negligent Charges

Tags: criminal-law, illinois

If it was just discovered that, 8 years ago, someone unknowingly gave medicine to another to cure an STD - that they weren't aware they had - is it still possible to press charges in the state of Illinois?

Comment: "Someone [..] gave medicine to another"... is one of those someone's you, or your dependent?

Comment: What charges do you contemplate? Do you mean to sue for money damages (and if so what were the damages) or to prosecute some for a crime which is usually what "press charges" refers to. "Negligent charges" doesn't really make sense in this context.

Answer (score 2):

The [statute of limitations](http://www.ilga.gov/legislation/ilcs/fulltext.asp?DocName=072000050K3-6) for criminal prosecution has passed in Illinois (3 years for a felony). There are some exceptions if the crime is murder, or the accused has fled the state. This is based on when the act occurred. A civil action for personal injury is also possible, which has a [statute of limitations of 2 years](http://www.ilga.gov/legislation/ilcs/fulltext.asp?DocName=073500050K13-202). This is "within 2 years next after the cause of action accrued": the statute does not specify what that means. Illinois follows what is known as the "discovery rule", meaning after the injury was discovered (for example a brain injury caused by a hit on the head), specifically ([Knox College v. Celotex](https://casetext.com/case/knox-college-v-celotex-corp), 88 Ill.2d 407)

> when a party knows or reasonably should know both that an injury has
>   occurred and that it was wrongfully caused, the statute begins to run
>   and the party is under an obligation to inquire further to determine
>   whether an actionable wrong was committed.

So the two primary question are, has an injury been suffered (probably, but not definitely), and is a lawsuit time-barred – that depends on the specifics of the case (hence consultation with an attorney is necessary).